# Declaring functions inside a loop in php

Tags: php, function

Suppose, I've a function like this -

```php
function something() {
       
}
```

Now, I need to loop this function by changing the function name like this -

```php
function something1() {
       
}

function something2() {
       
}

function something3() {
       
}

function something4() {
       
}
```

Is it possible to declare functions by loop ?? There are some other code staffs which is already looping inside of the for loop. But I can't change function names dynamically. Most importantly, I can't declare functions separately. I must do it inside a loop.

Can you help me to figure out that how can I do it??

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to change the function name? This sounds like an XY problem. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm 100% sure you should not declare functions in loop.

Comment: Please try to give context to the problem, why do you need to do this? so that we can recommend a better solution.

Comment: I want to add options to add task from admin panel. But It's required to have it's won function and I don't want to repeat those functions itself. Because all functions has same code, just need to change the function name because I can't re-declare functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your asking precisely, because declaring is different from looping, but...

In case you want to call a function by a variable name, you can achieve this by using the concept of variable functions.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php for more information.

```
<?php

function something1()
{
    echo 'First';
}

function something2()
{
    echo 'Second';
}

function something3()
{
    echo 'Third';
}

function something4()
{
    echo 'Fourth';
}

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $functionName = "something$i";
    echo $functionName() . " function is called.\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for calling in a loop, I want to declaring the function inside the loop. I need to declare all functions inside loop and it'll suffix the number (1, 2, 3, 4...) after the function name.

Comment: I don't want to repeat those functions itself. Because all functions has same code, just need to change the function name.

Answer (score 1):

I Suppose you need to MASS Declare functions. but that may not be performant and is probably not the right way. you can use `FUNCTION ARGUMENTS` instead.

```
function something ($number) {
     // Do Something With The Number you got.
}

for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    something($i); // pass the number to the function.
}
```

This is one of the ways of achieving this performantly.
You Can Learn more about it here: [Function Arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

**EDIT**

Although, this is not the best practice, but you can declare dynamic functions, but not in the form of functions really:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $func_name = "something$i";
    $$func_name = function ($i) {
        echo "Hello the number is: $i";
    };
    // And call it like
    print_r($$func_name($i));
}
```

The double `$$` is not a typo but a feature provided by PHP.

So for example:

```
$a = "b";
```

Then

```
$$a = "Hello";
```

Will evaluate to

```
$"b"
```

which would be processed by PHP like this: `$b = "Hello"`

And we are using that feature with functions instead.

Comment: Is it possible to print the number after the function name?? Something like this - https://github.com/saifullahsiddique/need-your-help-with-this-code/issues/1

Comment: How can I declare another function inside of something() function with the number??

Comment: @Saifullah why do you need to declare the function? if you can give context to your problem, I might help you.

Comment: @Saifullah updated my answer. check if it helps with your problem.